# Сайт не видит другие файлы

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Всем добрый день.
Сначала написал просто страничку, с подключением стилей и несколько изображений в отдельном файле.
Открыл в браузере все работает. Далее написал файл бэка(python + flask) и запустил на `localhost`, но страничка открылась без стилей и изображений. Стили я перенес в `<style></style>`, но изображения не удается никак подключить к сайту. Подскажите что делать. При выполнении бэка он каждый раз выдает 200 за запрос и 404 за каждый файл

расположение файлов:

`index.html`

`style.css`

- res (папка)

> background-body.png

> background-btn.png

> background-btn-disabled.png

[image: вот к приме]

несмотря на то что при открытии html файла через браузер, все отображается.

**Подскажите что делать пожалуйста**

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename= 'page.css')}}"/>
```

Функция url_for указывает путь для подгрузки стилей(из директории static)
Для подгрузки изображения его обычно размещают также в static

```
<img src="{{item}}" width="250" height="200" >
```

Обычно путь задают с помощью функционала шаблонизатора, а уже в обработчике передают значение переменной, например:

```
@app.route('/')
def index_page():
    return render_template('page.html',item = url_for('static', filename= 'image.jpeg'))
```

Comment: спасибо большое.